# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'hourId' cannot be null

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

My project is faculty allocation. when i try to insert data, it shows the following exception.

```
"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
Column 'hourId' cannot be null"
```

Can anyone help me how to overcome this problem?
Please provide sample code to avoid this exception.

My coding is

```
<%
    Connection con = null;
    String StaffName = request.getParameter("StaffName");
   // String subcode = request.getParameter("subcode");
    String hourId = request.getParameter("hourId");
    String daysId = request.getParameter("daysId");
    String date = request.getParameter("date");


  //String queryText = "insert into tblstaffallocation (StaffName, subcode,hourId, daysId, date) values('"+StaffName+"','"+subcode+"','+hourId+','+daysId+','+date+')";

    try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/StaffAllocation","root","success");

       // PreparedStatement stat = con.PrepareStatement();
        String updateString ="INSERT INTO tblstaffallocation (StaffName,hourId,daysId,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(updateString);


        preparedStatement.setString(1, StaffName);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, hourId);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, daysId);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, date);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        //int rst = stat.executeUpdate("insert into tblstaffallocation ('StaffName','hourId', 'daysId', 'date') values('"+StaffName+"','"+hourId+"','"+daysId+"','"+date+"')");

        %>
        <table cellpadding="4" border="1" cellspacing="4" align="center">
        <th>StaffName</th><th>hourId</th><th>daysId</th><th>date</th>
        <%
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from tblstaffallocation");
        while(rs.next()){
            rs.getString(1);
            rs.getString(2);
            rs.getString(3);
            rs.getString(4);

        }
        } catch (Exception e) { 
        out.print(e);

    }
```

Comment: change column_name to nullable

Comment: i tried that, when i insert data into the table, the coding works. but when i give select * from tblstaffallocation. all values entered other than staffname are stored as null value.

Comment: @user2951465 hourid column does not accpet null.Make sure that request.getParameter("hourId"); does not return null

Comment: @lucas i dont get you, what name should i provide? please be more specific

Comment: @user2951465 sorry, I meant hourId :)

Comment: Please, can you provide your table create statement? I guess you're doing a `setString` in the preparedStatement for not varchar columns setting some data that cannot be converted

Comment: staffname varchar(30); hourId int(11) not null; daysId int(11) not null; date datetime not null;

Comment: Ok, staffname is varchar and works well, what about the other columns? Also try to print your `hourId`, `daysId`, `date` parameters check the content (debugging or printing) and be sure they're not null

Comment: @Cirou i tried both the cases. i got this exception "java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'hourId' at row 1" when i modified columns into nullable :(

Comment: If you tried the code in the answer below that error means that `request.getParameter("hourId")` returns null and hourId is set as "". Check your GET parameters, something is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `hourId` has got a `NULL` value, so you must avoid it. For exemple, you could use:

```
String hourId = request.getParameter("hourId");
if (hourId==null)
    hourId="";
```

As long as the column accepts an empty string. If not, you must change the table definition to allow nulls:

```
 ALTER TABLE tblstaffallocation
   MODIFY COLUMN hourId INTEGER NULL;
```

Comment: i tried what you said it shows "java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'hourId' at row 1" exception

Comment: Column is an `int` so it is expecting an integer as input. If you give "" as parameter it returns an SQL Exception.

Comment: so with what i must replace ? please am a bit confused

Comment: Do you want to allow null values in `hourId` ? If so, try the given SQL. If not, you must decide what do you want in your table field when the request parameter is null. It will depend of your program... we cannot decide. It is common to put a `0` to represent a "no-value" field, but it will depend on what you use it for.

Answer (score 0):

This is good practice to have primary key per table and key property of the primary key is not allowing null values...
ORM/Hibernate strictly follows this principle where each entity/persistent bean should have primary key.. Answer to your question is you are trying to insert null value to a primary\non nullable  column .... so you are getting the exception... Below code is not good practice. If you intentionally made your column nullable then obviously no point trying to insert null/empty value.. Its better to design your data model before actually starting implementing the application.

```
if (hourId==null)
    hourId="";
```

Hope this will be helpful...

Cheers!

Comment: but if i want to keep previous value in database without touching it. how can i do that

Comment: Your previous value is null if it's giving the SQLException, you must either insert a zero, modify the table's column to accept strings, or set column default to 0.

Answer (score 0):

column hourId is set to not null while creating the table and you are trying to update with null value.
you can alter table to accept hourId as null or set some default value for hourId

Answer (score -1):

Let us check scenario of hibernate.
Solution :

> 1.check entity  mapping with table.
>   2. check the primary key and foreign key relationship.
>   3. primary key cannot be "not null" in table, it can be null in other table.